# Confusion with plural usage form

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

So I'm quite confused as to what word do I use in these sentences:

1. That equates to almost over 136,000 cars needing "repairs/repair".
2. DIY hail damage repair kits really "isn't/aren't" a good repair option.
3. Are you interested in learning more about our Assisted Living and Dementia Care "service/services"?

Comment: These are all covered before in various places pota, but would need a lot of finding. (1) would more idiomatically use the non-count usage which has the same form as the singular; 'needing repair' is really a fixed phrase. But the plural count usage 'repairs' is not wrong, and has very little difference in emphasis. Obviously with that number of cars, some are going to need more than one thing fixing. // (3) again gives you a choice.  The choice of 'service' is arguably singular count, not non-count. You're unlikely to have a plurality of service packages on offer, but if this _is_ the...

Comment: case, the plural form must be chosen. But the plural form can also be used to emphasise a single multi-component package. // (2) must have plural agreement ('aren't') with the plural subject ( ... kits).

Comment: I agree with all that, but I'd suggest that _service_ could refer to the whole organisation and _services_ to different kinds of help that they may offer.